# How to query for number of bytes that transmitted n a socket

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

I have a server that use TCP sockets, to get number of bytes that sent/received in this socket I can count number of bytes that sent or received using that specific socket but if I use functions like [TransmitPackets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then I can't get number of bytes that sent/received through that specific socket. Is there any way that I can get this information from the socket?

Comment: Do you use hooks or LSP to get the transmitted bytes?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean, but I want to get number of bytes that send through a socket that currently is sending data using `TransmitPackets` Windows API. And currently my only approach is avoiding `TransmitPackets` because I can't get this information without a low level programming like in `WireShark`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iphlpapi functions to get the active TCP connections statistics. Use the API GetExtendedTcpTable to get informations on all active connections including bytes sent/received, processid & TCP tuple.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I looked at [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I can't find sent/received bytes in any of the returned information, can you please help me further which parameter combination and returned structure lead to this information???

Comment: Use GetPerTcpConnectionEStats to get more information on the each TCP table entries.